# Company search results items covering the search results caption

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Performing a [common Company search on Careers](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/companies?searchTerm=unicorn&location=&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles), I noticed this weird thing:

> [image]

Putting on my Detective Hat, I went looking for the source of the misguided corn and finally realized it's the search results caption:

> 20 company pages for “unicorn”

Which was ruthlessly covered by the companies.

Can this please be fixed? Chrome 43.0.2357.65 for me, under Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this problem. A new member of the team (*cough*) was tweaking styles and inadvertently caused the regression seen. The change has been reverted and will be pushed to production soon.

Comment: Trial and error makes us good programmers, so now you're a better programmer - congrats! :-D

Comment: It's simply not good enough. This is Stack you know, not *the hyphen site* :D